# Custom attributes for CouchDB attachments

Tags: couchdb, attachment

I am trying to store multiple standalone attachments in a single CouchDB document, and assign arbitrary attributes (i.e. description) to each one.  Is there a convention for doing this?  From what I can tell, I cannot insert them in the `_attachments` structure directly.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify anything in `_attachments` directly as it is reserved for use by CouchDB.  However, it would be quite reasonable to store arbitrary attributes in a member such as `attachment_attributes`, using the same keys as in `_attachments` (the attachment names).  For example:

```
{
  "_attachments": {
    "foo.bar": ...,
    "xxx.yyy": ...
  },
  "attachment_attributes": {
    "foo.bar": {
      "description": "blah blah"
    },
    "xxx.yyy": {
      "description": "blah blah"
    }
  }
}
```