# Where should be stored attachment date

Tags: couchdb, attachment, database-schema

In CouchDB `_attachments` field can be [stored](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#attachments) `content_type` and `length` properties, but not `date`. Where can I store last modified date of attachment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom attributes for CouchDB attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556839/custom-attributes-for-couchdb-attachments)

Comment: This feature has own issue number as [COUCHDB-259](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-259) and have to be implemented. Stay tuned!